# wkhtmltopdf not get https images on laravel

Tags: https, laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I use wkhtmltopdf (snappy PDF) for get html to pdf.

For html to PDF it work perfect with internal image and external images with `http`  urls.

like I use `http://extradomain.com/logo.png` work perfect there is no problem to load image on PDF file. but when I use `https` like `https://exaple.com/logo.png` its not working at all.

I tried with :

```
$pdf->setOption('isRemoteEnabled',true);
```

but there is error of function not found and its not working.

how can I rander images from `https` ?